# Grepping in windows with a range and realtime output to a txt file

Tags: windows, grep, tail

I am running tail and grep from Server 2003 and am having problems with

a: Searching for a range (thats pipe delimited in the log file I am reading e.g.:

```
|100|2012/11/04 23:18:23|error string here|service name|host name|9|0|||0|824|3132|
```

b: outputting the matched lines in real time to a text file

This is what I'm using:

```
tail -f 20121106.log | grep -n "|8-9|" >> output.txt
```

I am basically looking to output to a text file anything it finds after the 6th pipe that is an 8 or a 9, which is an error according to my application.

if i don't output to a txt file and look for "|8|" or "|9|" (i cant get the range to work so i have to do one or the other) then it displays them correctly in real time in the cmd prompt window

Anyone can help me with this ?  Would be appreciated!

Cheers

Nige

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `GNU awk`:

```
tail -f 20121106.log | awk -F "|" '{ for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="8" || $i == "9") { print NR ":" $0; next } }' >> output.txt
```

Quick explanation:

Loop around fields after the 6th pipe, if the field is an "8" or "9" print the line number (`NR`), a colon (`:`) and the whole line (`$0`) that contains the matching field. `next` then breaks out of the loop to read the next line of input. HTH.

***EDIT:***

```
tail -f 20121106.log | perl -F\\\| -ane 'for ($i=6; $i<=@F; $i++) { if ($F[$i]=="8" || $F[$i] == "9") { print "$.:$_"; last } }' >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, GNU Awk is not set up on the box, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @user1802739: It's probably easier to simply install `awk`. Short of using `Perl`, you could use `grep` like this: `grep -n -e "|8|" -e "|9|"`, but it fails to check if the values occur after the sixth pipe. There are probably other ways to do this, but they'd all be a bit hackish and probably involve some sort of temp file. HTH.

Comment: @user1802739: I've added a `Perl` solution for you. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Steve, Im gonna give them both a go, appeciate it!